# invalid-meta The "main" field has to contain only 1 file per filetype; found multiple .js files

Tags: bower

> invalid-meta The "main" field has to contain only 1 file per filetype; found multiple .js files: ["dist/js/jquery.keyboard.js","layouts/keyboard-layouts-combined.js","layouts/keyboard-layouts-greywyvern.js","layouts/keyboard-layouts-microsoft.js"]

`bower install` is failing due to this error. How do I fix it?

```
"keyboard": "^1.26.25"
```

Answer (score 1):

Downgrade your bower to an earlier version that doesn't get those errors. I've resolved this by using a 1.4.x version. Try `npm i -g bower@~1.4.0`.